# What regulations are in place to protect consumer's investments in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, regulation, fscs

I know about [FSCS](http://www.fscs.org.uk/) (Financial Services Compensation Scheme), which will cover you in case your broker defaults, but it will only cover up to 50K GBP for investments; not particularly much.

What other regulatory scheme are in place? For example, in Japan brokers are required to manage consumer's asset separately and cannot use it for operation costs etc.